# Safety Recall - Dealers say "we don't have the parts for this"

Tags: safety, recall

So I've been consistently getting "recall" notices for my car and every time I receive one of those mails I immediately call the number on them. I am redirected to a dealer who always answers with the same thing: "we do not currently have parts for this recall, would you like us to notify you once we do so you can schedule an appointment for the fix?"

I respond with: "Yes please" and another month passes by with nothing happening.

Then I get another notice and so on.

This has been going for 1 year now and I can't get it done.

What should I do?

Comment: Physically visit the dealer and see the manager with all the evidence.

Comment: Try another dealer. If the number in the notice redirects everyone to just one dealer in a large area, it's not surprising if that dealership has run out of parts (and not reordering more parts is a good way to get rid of having to do more low-profit work!)

Comment: I agree with @alephzero - If there's another dealer in the area, go to them. Even if it's a subsidiary of the main one (ie: you've got a Chevrolet and there's a Buick dealership nearby), they should be able to take care of the recall as well. Going in person usually does a lot to get things rolling.

Comment: I would call the main customer service line for the manufacturer of your vehicle and see what advice they have. They have a higher interest in getting recalls completed. I had a recall where the part was unavailable for a while, but not a year!